# Is float property needs clear property too in css?

Tags: css

I am facing some issues using `float` property. When I have used it in a div that overlaps on its neighbor div, then I have to use clear property to get the real result. My question is :
Do I always need to use **clear property** after using float for two consecutive `div`s?

Comment: Provide some code to look at

Comment: no, not if they are wrapped in an element that is also floated.

Comment: please share your code what you have tried?

Comment: I think, yes you need unless you want those two consecutive divs to occupy 100% browser width. In that case, you need to add width:100%; with float: left; /*or right*/. 
with Float, divs tries to wrap each other from top left if they're floated left and right if they're floated right.

Comment: [clear](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) ("all about floats" from CSS-Tricks) and [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) are 2 important concepts when dealing with floats. Ultimately it's also related to [BFC](http://www.cssmojo.com/tags/bfc.html) (Block Formatting Context) which is… let's say an advanced topic in CSS (tl;dr when you read an advice like "also float it and it works, it'd work with `overflow: hidden` or `display: table` and other declarations which all confer BFC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clear` will be used only when you don't want your non-float elements AFTER float ones being affected.

I am not sure you have understood this already. It may be helpful if you would provide some code.